# IE9 is not redirecting to response body while uploading file using wicket modal page(embedded within a JSP)

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer-9, wicket, xmldocument, quirks-mode

I am using JSP to render a wicket modal page. When I am uploading a file, IE9 is not redirecting to response.

I debugged the code and found that IE9 returns `XMLDocument` as `null`. In this case, Wicket calls functions to create `XMLDocument`, and those functions are throwing errors. Also, I found that there is some error in the XML string which is passed to create the XML document.

Note: The default document mode of IE9 in my case in Quirks mode

Answer (score 0):

XMLDocument is not a supported interface in Quirks mode. Use MSXML as in the following examples:

- [Program the DOM in JScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms761349)
- [Mixing DOM and MSXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh180177)

Answer (score 0):

make the doc type as following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

and add the following meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>
```